# Tracking the current menu item in _layout by use of htmlhelper

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4, layout, menuitem

I found a post here about how to track the current menu item so that you can add an active class for css styling and from this code I created the following class within my Helpers folder:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace Project.Helpers
{
  public static class MenuExtensions
  {
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,string text,string action,string controller)
    {
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            li.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
    }
  }
}
```

I have added the line as advised to the web.config of the views folder as follows:

```
<add namespace="Project.Helpers" />
```

But when trying to add the following code to the layout:

```
@Html.MenuItem("Home", "Home", "Home")
```

I receive the following error:

**'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'MenuItem' and no extension method 'MenuItem' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Can you put `@using Project.Helpers` at the top of your view and see if that resolves the issue? If it does, then you need to put that markup into a different Web.config file..

Comment: yes this resolved the error, could it be that it is in the wrong section of the views web.config? I have it in <system.web.webPages.razor><pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"><namespaces></namespaces></pages></system.web.webPages.razor>

Comment: There are multiple configs. There is the global  one in the root folder. Then there is one under each area. Then there is one under each /Views/ folder. Put it in the most local one you can find. E.g, if you wanted to use it in /Areas/Test/Views/Home/Index.cshtml, put it in the web.config located at /Area/Test/Views/Web.config

Comment: its for the _layout of the site